# Format userid in Excel CSV not as exponential numbers

Tags: python, csv, data-mining, tweepy

i am collecting twitter data with python tweepy here is code

```
class listener (StreamListener):

def on_data(self, raw_data):

    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    print data.keys()
    tweet = data['text'].encode("utf-8")
    tweet_id = data['id']
    time_tweet = data['timestamp_ms']
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time_tweet) / 1000)
    new_date = str(date).split(" ") [0]
    print new_date
    user_id = data['user']['id']
    with  open('twitDB.csv','ab') as csvfile:
        myfile = csv.writer(csvfile)
        myfile.writerow([tweet_id,new_date,tweet,user_id])



    return True

def on_error(self, status_code):
    print status_code
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

[image]

But in Csv File for tweet_id and user_id are in 8.85132E+17 format how i resolve this ?

Comment: Please add your code *as text*, not images

Comment: Also, Excel is showing doubles in exponential format. Please show the raw data

Comment: You're loading it in Excel, which displays numbers in this format by default. Change the formatting of the cell

Comment: Thanks i change the format.

Comment: @asongtoruin by the time excel has loaded it in already, precision might be lost. What is the dtype of `data['id']`?

Comment: Excel has a maximum precision of 15 digits. It is already truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Place a tab character in front of tweet_id

`tweet_id = '\t' + data['id']`